# illegeal start of expression - for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans

I have researched this error, but I cant seem to find a fix. it seems so simple. here is my code:

```
private void butt1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       int num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(TxtField1));
       int num2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(TxtField2));
       int one = 1;

       for(int one = 0; one <= num2; one++){
    ta1.setText(String.valueOf("X"));
    }
```

the error is in the for loop
Edit: it works now, as in no illegal error, but now I want to print the char x, num2 amount of times. e.g. xxxx if num2 = 4.

Comment: seems like should be `Integer.parseInt(TxtField1.getText())` and  `for(one=1; num2>=one; one++){`

Comment: @PavneetSingh that wouldn't provide an int, I need an int value

Comment: try doing the initialization of one in the first parameter of the loop instead of before it.

Comment: @PavneetSingh the error still remains as an illegal start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :

```
for(int one = 1; one <= num2; one++) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(TxtField1));
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(TxtField2));
```

why?

you need to convert the string hold in the TxtField1 and TxtField2, but you just cant do it like String.valueOf(TxtField1)

as Pavneet Singh suggest: get the string of the TxtField1 and parse that to int.

```
 Integer.parseInt(TxtField1.getText())
```

on the other hand, this is wrong too:

```
for(one; num2>=one; one++){
```

Edit:

you mean for sure:

```
for(int one = 0; one <= num2; one++){
    ta1.setText(ta1.getText()+String.valueOf("X"));
}
```